# Is this the correct functioning of a reed type sensor in a stall warning system?

Tags: stall

I understand that this type of system works based on suction. According to what I read, at angles close to the critical angle of attack, the pressure near the leading edge is very low, this generates a greater pressure differential causing an increase in lift, this low pressure generates a suction in the stall warning system, causing the reed inside the horn to vibrate and generate a sound in the cabin, however, where the air is sucked from, is it sucked from the cabin? I feel that it makes no sense for the air to first enter through the horn and then leave again but this time with sound.

[image]

Comment: Sound can travel "upwind" in this case.  Air flow is indicated in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the airflow for the vibrating reed is sourced from inside the cabin. As long as there is enough mass airflow to set the reed into resonance, it will "bleat" audibly. All you need to do then is select the exact port location on the leading edge of the wing to start the bleat when the critical AoA is approached. Clever and foolproof- and the only moving part is the reed!